# Vue slot scopes within for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple slots within a `v-for` loop as shown below. Instead of binding my data for each slot, is there a way I can bind this data to all slots within the `v-for` loop?

```
<div class="vehicle-listing" v-for="(vehicle, index) in vehicles" :key="vehicle.id ? vehicle.id : 'undefined'+index">

    <div class="vehicle-listing__image">
        <slot name="listing-image" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
            Default content
        </slot>
    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-listing__title">
        <slot name="listing-title" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
            <slot name="listing-title__header" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
                Default content
            </slot>
            <slot name="listing-title__subtitle" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
                Default content
            </slot>
            <slot name="listing-title__price" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
                Default content
            </slot>
            <slot name="listing-title__favourites" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
               Default content
            </slot>
        </slot>
    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-listing__summary">
        <slot name="listing-summary" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
            Default content
        </slot>
    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-listing__finance">
        <slot name="listing-finance" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
            Default content
        </slot>
    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-listing__info">
        <slot name="listing-info" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
           Default content
        </slot>
    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-listing__location">
        <slot name="listing-location" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
           Default content
        </slot>
    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-listing__button-block">
        <slot name="listing-cta" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle">
           Default content
        </slot>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to bind to all slots at once.  You need to provide a binding for each slot individually.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots